# UDP ClientでSend時の指定ポート以外でレスポンスを受け取ることはできるのか?

Tags: c#, udp

C#でUDP Clientを使って通信を行おうとしています。
device Aに以下のようなポート設定でSendすると、レスポンスとしてlocalport=47808, destport=57575で返ってきていたため、udpのRecieveできるのですが、device Bでは固定でlocalport=47808, destport=47808で返ってきます。
この場合、device Bからのレスポンスを受け取る方法はあるのでしょうか?

ともに送信は成功しているのですが、device Bからの受信のみ失敗(timeout)してしまいます。

送信 : host --->(57575)---(47808)---> device A
受信 : host <---(57575)---(47808)<--- device A

送信 : host --->(57575)---(47808)---> device B
受信 : host <---(47808)---(47808)<--- device B

```
var localport = 57575;
var destport = 47808;
var destIpAddr = "192.168.0.1";

using (var udp= new UdpClient(localport))
{
  udp.Send(sendBytes, len, destIpAddr, destPort);
  System.Net.IPEndPoint endPoint = null;
  var recvBytes = udp.Receive(ref endPoint);
}
```

Comment: `localport = 47808` ではダメですか？

Comment: bind したポートでしか受信できないので、送信ポートを変えられないのであれば、UdpClient を２つ作るしかないのでは。

Comment: @sayuri  諸事情がありlocalport=47808は使えない環境なのです...

Comment: 諸事情って、既存のサービスが 47808 ポートを使っているってことですか？
既存のサービスの設定変更が出来れば、NIC に複数の IP アドレスを持たせて受信できるかも。
変更できなければ無理です。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sayuri さんがコメントしてらっしゃいますが device A に対して 47808 ポートから送信したら 47808 に返してくれる気もします。
そうでない場合は、どちらでも受信できるように作ることも出来ます。

```
const int localPort1 = 57575;
const int localPort2 = 47808;

static byte[] SendRecv(string destIpAddr, int destPort, 
                        byte[] sendBytes, int len) {
    byte[] recvBytes;
    using (var udp1 = new UdpClient(localPort1))
    using (var udp2 = new UdpClient(localPort2)) {
        // Connect するかどうかは要件しだい
        udp1.Connect(destIpAddr, destPort);
        udp2.Connect(destIpAddr, destPort);
        var t1 = udp1.ReceiveAsync();
        var t2 = udp2.ReceiveAsync();
        udp1.Send(sendBytes, len);
        var index = Task.WaitAny(t1, t2);
        if (index == 0) {
            Console.WriteLine($"{localPort1} から受信しました。");
            recvBytes = t1.Result.Buffer;
            CancelIo(udp2, t2);
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine($"{localPort2} から受信しました。");
            recvBytes = t2.Result.Buffer;
            CancelIo(udp1, t1);
        }
    }
    return recvBytes;
}

// 非同期 IO のキャンセル
static void CancelIo(UdpClient udp, Task task) {
    CancelIo(udp.Client.Handle);
    try {
        task.Wait();
    } catch (AggregateException ex) 
         when (ex.InnerException is SocketException) {
        var port = ((IPEndPoint)udp.Client.LocalEndPoint).Port;
        Console.WriteLine($"{port} の受信をキャンセルしました。");
    }
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool CancelIo(IntPtr hFile);
```

Comment: 上記のようにudpClientを2つ用意することで受信することができました。

Answer (score 1):

> 諸事情がありlocalport=47808は使えない環境なのです

そうであれば

> 受信 : host <---(47808)---(47808)<--- device B

の受信は諦めてください。47808にbindしない限り、47808宛のメッセージを受信することはできません。